# PyPlot savefig() error 'TrueType font is missing table' when using ttc font

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, julia

I am using PyPlot package from Julia language on macOS 10.13. Here is my code that generates the problem:

```
using PyPlot
PyPlot.svg(true)

function myplot()
  my_font=matplotlib[:font_manager][:FontProperties](fname = "/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttc")
  fig, ax = subplots()
  ax[:plot](rand(10), rand(10), linewidth = 2)

  for tick in ax[:xaxis][:get_major_ticks]()
    tick[:label][:set_fontproperties](my_font)
  end
  for tick in ax[:yaxis][:get_major_ticks]()
    tick[:label][:set_fontproperties](my_font)
  end
  savefig("figure.pdf")
end

myplot()
```

As you see, I need to change the font of the tick labels to Helvetica, which is available on my mac through the ttc file. The figure shows up normally in Jupyter Notebook. However, with `savefig()`, it does not work:

```
RuntimeError('TrueType font is missing table',)
```

I have already deleted `~/.matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache` and `~/.matplotlib/tex.cache`. What do I still need to do to make `savefig()` work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should change a font

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Calibri'
```